# How to access files on Ceph directly as URL

Tags: storage, ceph, radosgw

I need a storage system with the following requirements:
1. It should support data/service clustering
2. It should be open-source so that I can extend functionalities later if needed
3. It should support file system because I want to access some files as public url(direct access). So that I can store my scripts in these files and directly refer these files.
4. Supports some kind of authentication
5. I want it to be on premise (Not cloud).

Ceph seems to qualify all the criteria but **does it support the public access of files just like a URL(Point 3) ?** It has ability to generate temporary URLs though but I want permanent URLs for few files.

Answer (score 0):

You could run Nextcloud and have your data volume (and database, if you feel so inclined) stored on the Ceph cluster.  That's open-source, you can setup direct links to files including permanent links, and is authenticated.